# Where can I store constants for a flutter app?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, flutter-layout, mobile-development

I have a few constants that need to be stored such as List of menu options, default color etc.Where is the best place to store such constants and what would be the best format( declare a class,just static file etc) ?

Answer (score 0):

Just create one Folder like common_widget or constants and create one file in that refer effective design in dart [here](https://dart.dev/guides/language/effective-dart/design)

your `constant.dart` file

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class MyConstant {
  static Color myColor = Colors.red;
  static Icon myIcon = Icon(
    Icons.add,
    color: Colors.green,
  );
  static TextStyle myStyle = TextStyle(
    fontSize: 27,
    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
    color: Colors.blue,
  );
}
```

Your Widget file. and import the constant file in your widget file

```
 Column(
      children: [
        Text(
          'store constants for a flutter app',
          style: MyConstant.myStyle,
        ),
        IconButton(
          icon: MyConstant.myIcon,
          onPressed: () {},
        ),
        Divider(
          color: MyConstant.myColor,
        )
      ],
    ),
```

Your result screen-> [image]

Comment: You don’t need to create a class, simply add your constants as `const kSomeConstant = “myConstantValue”` in a dart file as Constants in Flutter are given a prefix of `k` and that should be it.